# Email alerts on failure in Airflow without turning on "Allow less secure apps"

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

To send email failure alerts, Airflow needed an SMTP username and password for authentication. I am using google mail for that but google treats all apps that use username and password as less secure. So to make it work, I need to enable "Allow less secure apps" in the google account settings.
Is there a way to use google SMTP mail without turning on "Allow less secure apps" settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a google app password for a specific application and then disable "Allow less secure apps".This google documentation may help you [google answer](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en).
You can use the app password instead of your account password.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this but the only issue will be that enabling "2-factor" authentication will tie it to a personal phone number, we wanted to keep this account accessed by all developers in the team.